# Warning of 409 Conflict issue in API while creating the same group again after deleting the group in Google workspace and from admin console

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-workspace, google-groups-api

We are using admin SDK API for creating a group in domain by GDriveFlow app. After existing group in Google workspace  admin console, We deleted this group and again creating the same group with API then we are getting the below error message:

```
409 Conflict
{
  "code": 409,
  "errors": \[
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "Entity already exists.",
      "reason": "duplicate"
    }
  \],
  "message": "Entity already exists."
}
```

When we checked the same group there is no existing same group in Google workspace  admin console.

When we are creating the same group from  Google workspace admin console and it is saying :

"A group or alias already exists with this email" .

But when I am searching the group in Google workspace admin console, I am not getting this group in console.

When I am searching same group with Method: groups.aliases.list in API explorer and getting: 404 not found msg in attached screen shot .

Can you please let me know why is this happening and not creating the group even it is not in domain ?

I have also reported this issue in Google Issue tracker at : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184303064

I am attaching the screenshots for creation of Group with these methods:

1- Manual by admin console, 2- SDK API by application,  3- By API explorer in Google workspace as below:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour. Do you have a way to reproduce this? (1) Create a group, (2) delete it and (3) try to create again with same email? I tried this and could create the group after having deleted it. About the steps I suggested, how were (1) and (2) done, through the Admin console? Via API?

Comment: @Iamblichus 1- is done through API 2- is done through Admin console. 3- Again create with API. This behavior am getting 409 conflict error  in 3rd case via API in our two domains.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, even when creating/deleting the group the way you just mentioned. Can you provide the code related to the requests you are making?

Comment: @Iamblichus Yes I am also able to create/delete/create with a new email id but I am not able to create again with old email. I am also trying to create in API explorer and still getting the same issue. You can see my comments at  #7 and screenshots in issue tracker:https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184303064 of Google same as in my app also.

Comment: Well, I'm also using the same old email for the group when recreating it.

Comment: Since this issue is about a specific group and cannot be reproduced otherwise, I'd consider contacting [Workspace support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213).

Comment: Yes, It is a known issue. I already contacted and reported this issue to Workspace support. As Google Support team says: "It looks like we might be affected by an known issue in Google Workspace  Groups and there is a workaround available." You can check the workaround at issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184303064

Comment: I am having the same issue, apparently it is something that can be reproduced when deleting in a certain sequence. No solution from Google just yet...

Comment: You should add the workaround remark as the answer - I will vote for it. That makes this question easier to be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Support Team replied me as :

"It looks like we might be affected by an known issue in Google Workspace  Groups and there is a workaround available."

So they told me if this type of issue comes then do these steps as below:

These steps are using the UI but this may be achieved by using the APIs as well.

A. Create a new user with this group mail Id(Old mail Id)

1. Browse to: https://admin.google.com/ac/users
2. Click `Add new user`
3. Enter “primary email address” with with same email Id(old) and other required fields
4. Click `ADD NEW USER`

B. Delete user created in the previous step:

1. Browse to: https://admin.google.com/ac/users
2. Add filter `Email`
3. Enter email address used for previous user creation
4. Click `APPLY`
5. Click on the user to navigate to their profile of that group mail id as user into domain
6. In left pane, click `DELETE USER`
7. Select `Don’t transfer data`
8. Click `DELETE USER`

C. Proceed to perform the action that was previously blocked and again create the group with same email Id.

This will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I got another workaround from Google Support:

1. Add the email address to an existing user account as an alias and save it.
2. Delete the alias and save it.

After that I was able to create the group.